# Does Bluestacks, emulator for Android, access the PCs bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluestacks

I am doing some research on apps, in particular https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.z2software.btpluginhidd

To do what I need to is an emulator of android that can access the PCs bluetooth and is able to activate it. Thus, I ask if bluestacks is able to perform it.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can’t because BlueStacks doesn’t support Bluetooth at this moment (even until the last update on may 2013). Fortunately you can send and receive from your laptop to mobile devices, and fortunately again there are several shared folders available for PC and BlueStacks. The tricks is by using pc to send or receive files between mobile devices and BlueStacks.

[Have a look](http://www.oaultimate.com/computers/bluestacks-and-bluetooth.html)